# How to handle long running process using TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, long-running-processes

I have started learning **TPL** in C# recently. We have a windows service that does some functionality.

```
I have to perform each job paralelly rather than  sequentially.
```

Each job will be taking **more than 10 mins to complete**. So, i am considering this as **long running process.**

So, i guess i **would not be creating ThreadPool for this** , as it is meant for short time threads.

how to handle long running tasks using TPL. Suppose if i have 100 jobs to process,

```
Do i need to create 100 tasks for long running process ?
```

Please clarify on above.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` when creating the task? Then it's likely not to use the thread pool...

Comment: Is the long running process a CPU bound process or an I/O bound process?

Comment: Its a CPU bound process

Comment: Suppose i have hundered jobs to process, do i need t create 100 threads ?

Comment: @JohnSKeet. If i have lot of jobs to process , will it create lot of threads ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. It is made for long-running work that might confuse the thread-pool heuristics. As of .NET 4.5 this always runs your code on a new thread. You can still use all other TPL features.